# How can I search for the longest xml nodes in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have some xml data where I'd like to find the longest nodes. For example...

```
<data>
    <name>Miranda</name>
    <type>Horse</type>
</data>
<data>
    <name>Corny</name>
    <type>Unicorn</type>
</data>
```

So if I searched for the longest name node in the above it should return "Miranda" and if I searched for the longest type node it should return "Unicorn". How can I do this?

Comment: which OS? do you have `gnu utils` available?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP. What's gnu utils?

Comment: I guess notepad++ cannot do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not all automatic but if you have the XML Tools plugin (can be downloaded via Plugin Manager)...

... select **Tools->XML Tools->Evaluate XPath Expression** and enter this in your expression:

```
/some/data/name
```

... then click **[Evaluate]**

I know it will show all name tags but you can just scroll through it and manually look for the longest string.

**PS**: the extra  tag above was added because your XML by itself is not a valid XML file.  I have to format it like below to make it traversable:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<some>
    <data>
        <name>Miranda</name>
        <type>Horse</type>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>Corny</name>
        <type>Unicorn</type>
    </data>
</some>
```